# Eclipse formatter line breaking assignments and method invocations

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way I can configure eclipse to prefer breaking a long assignment by putting the '=' on a new line, and avoid breaking on a '.' character for a method invokation. I've noticed a bunch of settings like:

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.alignment_for_arguments_in_allocation_expression" value="16"/>
```

that can be added to an xml file that can be used to specify formatting, but I'm not sure which settings I should change to have the desired effect. Are these configurations documented somewhere (I tried Googling some relevant terms to no avail).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting you're looking for regarding assignment line breaks is in:

```
Window (menu) > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter
> Edit... (on active profile) > Line Wrapping (tab) > Expressions
> Assignments
```

where you can select your preferred line wrapping policy and indentation policy.

As for avoiding line breaks, still on the `Line Wrapping` tab, change the line wrapping policy on `Function Calls` > `Qualified invocations` to "Do not wrap".

In both cases, you can play with the preview width to see what effect the various policies will have on how your code is formatted.